# How to get records between dates that are on different rows?

Tags: mysql

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a3662/2)

I have a table called `Event` which logs when players on a multi-player server login and logout.

```
+----------------------------------------------+
| id | username | type   | timestamp           |
+----------------------------------------------+
| 1  | Player3  | login  | 2014-01-14 17:00:00 |
| 2  | Player4  | login  | 2014-01-14 17:00:00 |
| 3  | Player4  | logout | 2014-01-14 17:30:00 |
| 4  | Player1  | login  | 2014-01-14 18:00:00 |
| 5  | Player2  | login  | 2014-01-14 19:00:00 |
| 6  | Player3  | logout | 2014-01-14 19:00:00 |
| 7  | Player1  | logout | 2014-01-14 20:00:00 |
| 8  | Player2  | logout | 2014-01-14 20:00:00 |
+----------------------------------------------+
```

I'd like to get a unique list of usernames for those who were online at a specific timestamp. So for example, if I want to know who was online at `2014-01-14 18:00:00` it should return:
`Player1` and `Player3`.

What I have tried so far:

```
SELECT * FROM event 
WHERE (timestamp <= '2014-01-14 18:00:00' AND type = 'login')
AND (timestamp >= '2014-01-14 18:00:00' AND type = 'logout');
```

EDIT2:

`Session` table:

```
+------------------------------------------------------+
| id | login_event | logout_event | duration (seconds) |
+------------------------------------------------------+
| 1  | 1           | 6            | xxxxxx             |
| 2  | 2           | 3            | xxxxxx             |
| 3  | 4           | 7            | xxxxxx             |
| 4  | 5           | 8            | xxxxxx             |
+------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more complicated that your query.  You need people whose most recent action at that time was login, essentially:

```
SELECT username,
       max(case when type = 'login' and timestamp <= '2014-01-14 18:00:00'
                then timestamp
           end) as lastlogin,
       max(case when type = 'logout' and timestamp <= '2014-01-14 18:00:00'
                then timestamp
           end) as lastlogout
FROM event 
GROUP BY username
HAVING (lastlogout is null or lastlogout < lastlogin) and lastlogin is not null;
```

EDIT:

By the way, if you know the login/logout records are totally accurate (never missed, never duplicated), you can also do this with a count (which some might find easier to follow):

```
SELECT username,
       sum(type = 'login' and timestamp <= '2014-01-14 18:00:00') as numlogins,
       sum(type = 'logout' and timestamp <= '2014-01-14 18:00:00') as numlogouts
FROM event 
GROUP BY username
HAVING numlogins > numlogouts;
```

EDIT (on session):

The query on the session table looks easier:

```
SELECT lie.username
from session s join
     event lie
     on s.login_event = lie.id join
     event loe
     on s.logout_event = loe.id
where lie.timestamp <= '2014-01-14 18:00:00' and
      loe.timestamp >= '2014-01-14 18:00:00';
```

That works and would probably be better on small tables.  On larger tables, I don't think it would work so well.  What would work is a session table that has the two timestamps in it, with an index on them.

Comment: Thanks! I'm intended for login/logout records to be accurate. But which one performs better with a lot of records in the table?

Comment: The performance should be similar for these two queries.  You can improve performance by putting an index on `timestamp` and adding a where clause to the first version, such as `where timestamp between '2014-01-13' and '2014-01-14 18:00:00'` (assuming people don't spend more than 42 hours logged in).  That will significantly reduce the volume of data.

Comment: Can you take a look at my edit? I have another table called Session, would it be better to query off that table?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT username FROM
(SELECT username,timestamp as intime,
       (SELECT min(timestamp)
        FROM event e2
        WHERE e2.username = e1.username
          AND e2.timestamp > e1.timestamp
        AND e2.type = 'logout') as outtime
FROM event e1
WHERE e1.type = 'login'
)t1
WHERE '2014-01-14 18:00:00' BETWEEN t1.intime AND t1.outtime;
```

you can pair up the timestamp as intime and outtime and then see if your specified time is between those times. [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a3662/10/0)

or you can use `HAVING` to take out 1 level of subquery.

```
SELECT username,timestamp as intime,
 (SELECT min(timestamp)
 FROM event e2
 WHERE e2.username = e1.username
 AND e2.timestamp > e1.timestamp
 AND e2.type = 'logout') as outtime
FROM event e1
WHERE e1.type = 'login'
HAVING '2014-01-14 18:00:00' BETWEEN intime AND outtime;
```